# eno1 interface has disappeared, ethernet 'unclaimed'

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, ethernet, interface

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS which uses NetworkManager to manage internet connections.

For a while, everything was fine with my computer - ethernet worked as plug & play - but recently I created a new, separate account on it, and, since I was leaving for a while, set up ssh access to it. This involved setting a static ip using netplan. My netplan configuration (at `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`) looks like this, then:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.69/24
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

I'm aware this may be a possible cause of the problem I'm having, but I'm not certain.

Anyway, after a couple of days, I stopped being able to ssh into my computer. This was because, for whatever reason, Ubuntu had decided that the ethernet interface `eno1` had disappeared. After getting someone to change port forwarding rules so I could ssh via WiFi, I found that `ifconfig` gives:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 178597  bytes 15686085 (15.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 178597  bytes 15686085 (15.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx200db0187d26: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::536:3e32:5a6f:df0a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 20:0d:b0:18:7d:26  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 358159  bytes 114355653 (114.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 17  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 609759  bytes 486071543 (486.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What's interesting about this is that there is a mention of `Ethernet`, but I don't know what this means in this context - does it mean that the wireless adapter is acting as an ethernet adapter and I am in fact accessing my computer via ethernet? Or does it mean something else entirely?

Obviously my adapter can't have just disappeared - as shown by the output of `lshw -C network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7100000-f711ffff memory:f7139000-f7139fff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.1
       logical name: wlx200db0187d26
       serial: 20:0d:b0:18:7d:26
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=5.4.0-52-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.15 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

I think the `UNCLAIMED` here might be a clue to solving this, but after searching through the internet and trying a billion different solutions, none of them seem to have fixed it. Advice would be very much appreciated, thank you.

---

**UPDATE** this issue turned out to be caused by a physically broken ethernet adapter. I had to purchase a USB ethernet interface in order to get ethernet connection again.

Comment: What I find unsettling is that your network adapter no longer has a "logical name" attached to it - that would have been `eno1`. Btw, your netplan config looks right, and this should not have any impact of the logical ID of your network interface.

Comment: Yes, it's a tad worrying, isn't it. It used to have a logical name too, before I tried to mess around with netplan.

Comment: I honestly have no idea about what could cause the logical name to disappear, sorry mate. Are you running latest Ubuntu kernel 5.4.0-52? Maybe you could try adapting the HWE line of kernels, although I'm not yet sure how to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe e1000e` and also: `dmesg | grep e100`

Comment: @chili555 the output of that command is _huge_...

Comment: Please paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 sorry for the delay. Please find the paste here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ycNYSXDJFg/

Comment: :Modules linked in" Usually happens when there are repeated near or actual crashes. Please run `sudo dmesg | less` and scroll down until you see Modules linked in and paste the fifteen lines *before* it and give us the link. Get out of 'less' with q.

Comment: @chili555 hey chilli, thanks for being willing to help. Here's the paste: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QgT8yK6Zb3/  (FWIW, I do know how to use less ;))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115635/discussion-between-chili555-and-jthistle).